# How to use units given for heatsink thermal resistance?

Tags: thermal, heatsink, specifications

In looking for a heatsink I came across a company giving the thermal resistance of extrusions in °C/W/3in.  How do I use this?

Say I use an extrusion with a specification of 1.5 °C/W/3in and get it cut to a length of 10 inches.  I want to know delta-T for a 100 W input.

Here's my math:

```
delta_T = (1.5 °C/W/3in * 100 W) / (10 in / 3 in) = 45 °C
```

Is this correct?

Here's an example of a heatsink they make:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct, however I'd be cautious about using it for lengths much longer than 6" (assuming the semiconductor is mounted near the center) as the spreading along the length will begin to increase the temperature delta, and also the way the convection works may have an effect.

Maybe the manufacturer has curves available, or you can find a manufacturer that does and guesstimate the effects.

If you have a number of similar loads distributed along the heatsink, the performance should be better. AAVID Thermalloy says:

> Natural Convection: 1.38 based on 70 C temp rise above ambient.
> Thermal resistance is calculated based on a single 1" (25.4mm) square
> heat source centered on the heat sink. If you have distributed loads,
> then you can expect 10% better performance in natural convection and
> 20% better performance in forced convection

When you get down to the last 20-30% of performance, mock-up and testing is probably the best approach.

Comment: The heat source in this case will be evenly distributed (a bunch of closely spaced MOSFETs.  I realized that the numbers given by heatsink extrusion providers are based on a 1x1 in point load a the center of a 3 in length of the UUT.  You are right, this has to be characterized through a rough prototype.  I'll mess with FEA simulation but I think a prototype isn't something you can avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's right.

The heatsink may be tested at 3 inches length, so a longer heatsink may slightly underperform if it's asked to carry lots of heat lengthwise.  but if you have several heat sources along the length of the heatsink this should not be a problem.